# Environment Files in Linux (Bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I have seen below files exists on system. 
Need to understand which all environment files are run in different scenario.

```
/etc/profile
$HOME/.bashrc
$HOME/.bash_profile
$HOME/.profile
```

1. When we login to the server through putty
2. When we run bash command to create a subshell
3. When we run a script through crontab
4. When we run a script in the shell with "sh script.sh" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## A glance at the documentation

To answer this, consult `man bash` and go down to the `FILES` part where it says:

> `/etc/profile`
>        The  systemwide  initialization  file, executed for
>        login shells
>
> `/etc/bash.bashrc`
>                The systemwide per-interactive-shell startup file
>
> `/etc/bash.bash.logout`
>                The systemwide login shell cleanup  file,  executed
>                when a login shell exits
>
> `~/.bash_profile`
>                The  personal initialization file, executed for login shells
>
> `~/.bashrc`
>                The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
>
> `~/.bash_logout`
>                The individual login shell cleanup  file,  executed
>                when a login shell exits

Not in the FILES section but also in the manpage is the `.profile`. Basically Bash prefers `.bash_profile` if it exists. In contrast: `/etc/profile` is processed before any dotfiles and independently of their existence.

For further info, the startup procedure of Bash is explained under INVOCATION in the Bash manpage.

## Applying this to the scenario

> When we login to the server through putty

This should be (but possibly configurable?) considered a "login". Thus `/etc/profile` will run and then `~/.bash_profile` if it exists. If it does not exist, `~/.profile` will run (if it exists).

> When we run bash command to create a subshell

Depends on what exactly this means, is there perhaps any commandline showing what you mean by subshell? Normal `(` and `)` in a shell script will not trigger any of the files, but interactive `bash` will run `.bashrc`.

> When we run a script through crontab

Simlar to next question. Note that in this situation, there will not be a prompt defined which causes most bashrc-files to return immediately (even if they are loaded). Compared to an "interactive" script invocation from the commandline, this can cause certain environment variables to be missing in the script being run through crontab.

> When we run a script in the shell with "sh script.sh" command.

This is actually distribution dependent. On Debian-based systems, `sh` = `/usr/bin/dash` which means that none of the files from the list will be considerd. Call `man dash` (and look at the FILES section) for details.

On CentOS-based systems, `sh` = `/bin/bash` will consult `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` in that order (skipping if not existent).

Comment: Thanks I went through the detail . All were clear except script run through crontab . Can you clarify which all environment variable file will be executed if I run scripts through crontab.